# TFS build do not throw error with new build controller

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have configured a new build controller

## Current Controller config:

Windows server 2008 R2
TFS : Tfs2012.Update4
Visual studio 2015

## New Controller config:

Window server 2016 standard
TFS : Tfs2012.Update4
Visual studio 2015

If i trigger a build to current controller if there is a error it throws the errors.

But if i trigger a build to new build controller build get stuck at some point and never comes out. It do not throw any error.

Moreover, no logs get copied to TFS server, only empty folder gets created with Defintionname_time.

I tried manually building the solution using msbuild command it get succeeded.

I am new to TFS build please help.

Answer (score 0):

Window server 2016 is not supporeted for TFS 2012.

Please refer to [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) for details.

You should consider migrating to the latest vNext build system [TFS 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update3) or even [TFS 2018](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes).

The xaml buil system is too old and not supporeted by TFS team.

Reference [Why You Should Switch to Build VNext](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext)

Comment: @hanu Is the answer helps you? You can upgrade to vNext build system or still use the xaml build system but with Window server 2012 or 2008